# Entity framework not showing values for a specific column in query result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL Server database mapped in Entity Framework 6.

**Database Model in EF**
[image]

The problem is that when I query the `Employee` table for an employee or for all employees, it doesn't return the `Equipments` mapped with the particular employee. The `Equipments` column is empty.

The results are being displayed in a `DataGridView`

**Query Result for a Particular Employee**
[image]

I queried like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE EmployeeID = 5;
```

What seems to be the problem? Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: i am wondering what is Equiments in your query result (2nd screen shot)

Comment: Equipment table refers Employee I understand

Comment: Are you using Linq with Entity Framework? If so, please paste your linq query that you are using.

Comment: No, I am using `cntxt.Employees.SqlQuery('SQL query here');`

Comment: can you try `cntxt.Employees.Include(b => b.Euipments).Where(e=>e.EmployeeId==5);`

Comment: Just to be safe, make sure that your Employee has Equipments linked to him on your database. Also make sure the edmx file is properly saved (don't change it and close without saving).

Comment: @Sclerosis provide your code in your question regarding on how you are using EF to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
cntxt.Employees.Include(b => b.Euipments).Where(e=>e.EmployeeId==5);
```

Comment: you mean `Include` does not accept lambda expression ?

Comment: @Sclerosis you need to import `System.Data.Entity` for lambda expression `Include`

Comment: Still not showing equipments. The `equipments` column stays empty

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples in Linq that would match your query but also include the equipment.

```
using (var context = new EmployeeContext()) {
    var employeeData = context.Employees.Where(p=> p.EmployeeID == 5)
                       .Include(t => t.Equipment).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or

```
using (var context = new EmployeeContext()) {
    var employeeData = context.Employees.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Employee E JOIN Equipment EE ON E.EmployeeID = EE.EmployeeID WHERE E.EmployeeID = @id", new SqlParameter("@id", 5)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I would suggest reading how to pass the parameters here

[Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)

[Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework 6:](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: I tried the LINQ query, and the `equipments` column is still empty

Comment: Hi @Sclerosis, you need to validate that all your data is correct in the database. Run a SQL profiler when executing the Linq query and see what SQL query EF 6 is generating. Then analyse it and find why the data is not returning.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out